# Is it possible to call .NET Generics in a dynamic way?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, dynamic

*Names of entities have been altered to protect their identities...*

I've created a class called AnimalSearch(Of AnimalType As Animal(Of Int32))

```
Public Class AnimalSearch(Of AnimalType As Animal(Of Int32))

End Class
```

I can call this class like this:

```
Dim s As New AnimalSearch(Of Monkey)()
```

However, I don't know at the time of the call what type "Monkey" will be.

I've been trying the following setup, but can't seem to get anywhere:

```
Public Shared Function GetAnimalSearchResults(criteria As SearchCriteria, animalType As Type) As SearchResults
    Dim s As New AnimalSearch(Of animalType)()
    ' ... (etc.)
End Function
```

Which I then call from another class somewhere like so:

```
Dim results As SearchResults = GetAnimalSearchResults(criteria, GetType(Monkey))
```

Elsewhere, I might call:

```
Dim results As SearchResults = GetAnimalSearchResults(criteria, GetType(Giraffe))
```

It's the constructor (`Dim s As New AnimalSearch(Of animalType)()`), which is the problem.  It can be reproduced by using the following, slightly more simple code:

```
Dim t As Type = GetType(Monkey)
Dim s As New AnimalSearch(Of t)()
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx

There as an advantage it says:

> Type Safety. Generic types enforce compile-time type checking. Types based on Object accept any data type, and you must write code to check whether an input data type is acceptable. With generic types, the compiler can catch type mismatches before run time.

So i don't expect to work it the way you try to, because in your example the compile doesn't know which type you wan't to create the generic for (as you read the type through the `GetType` Method).

But instead of creating the generic dynamically you could just create the Generic of the type of a Baseclass (or Interface) instead.

**Edit:**

Here as an example:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething()

      Dim obj As New mySpecClassA
      Dim obj2 As New mySpecClassB

      Dim gen As New myGenericClass(Of myBaseClass)

      gen.DoSomething(obj)
      gen.DoSomething(obj2)
   End Sub
   Public Class myGenericClass(Of T As myBaseClass)
      Public Function DoSomething(ByVal param As T) As String
         '** Do something
         Return param.Name
      End Function
   End Class
   Public Class mySpecClassA
      Inherits myBaseClass


   End Class
   Public Class mySpecClassB
      Inherits myBaseClass


   End Class
   Public Class myBaseClass
      Public Name As String
   End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix runtime and compile-time like that in .NET, but you can get close by using open generic types:

```
Dim s As IAnimalSearch = Activator.CreateInstance (
    GetType (AnimalSearch (Of )).MakeGenericType (animalType))
```

You will have to provide `AnimalSearch (Of T)` with a non-generic interface (I called it `IAnimalSearch`) in order to be able to manipulate it, though.